# Incorrect index generation when used with babel [greek]

Tags: babel, greek, makeindex

I am trying to index a document with several greek phrases. Using babel and `\textgreek` all went well ... until I got to the index. All entries from the `\frontmatter` (with roman page numbers) get lost.

Editing the .idx-files manually and freezing them, I can work around the problem, but this can't be the solution.
Without the greek in the babel-options, the problem does not exist, but unfortunately I need it ...

Has anyone an idea how the the .idx could be generated correctly (without the unnecessary `\fontencoding` in the `\indexentry`)? Thanks a lot.

```
%TexLive 2018
%pdfLaTeX or luaLaTeX
%
%Index without greek:
% --------------
%Riesenindex
%Auszeichnung, 1         Seite, 2
%In Fussnote, iii        Text, ii, 1
%                        TEXT, iii
%
%Index with greek
% --------------
%Auszeichnung, 1         Text, 1
%Seite, 2

%first 3 lines of .idx with greek
% ------------------------------
%\indexentry{Text}{{\fontencoding  {OT1}\selectfont  ii}}
%\indexentry{Text@\textsc{Text}}{{\fontencoding  {OT1}\selectfont  iii}}
%\indexentry{In Fussnote}{{\fontencoding  {OT1}\selectfont  iii}}

%error message in .ilg with greek
% ------------------------------
%!! Input index error (file = IndexTstMaster.idx, line = x):
%   -- Illegal space within numerals in second argument.

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass [paper=C5]{scrbook} 

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage [ngerman]{babel}  % english
\usepackage [main=ngerman,greek.ancient]{babel}  % english
\usepackage{imakeidx}      % with xindy there is no improvement
\makeindex[title=Riesenindex]

\begin {document}
   \frontmatter 
   Etwas Text\index{Text} hier;
   \newpage
   Etwas mehr Text\index{Text@\textsc{Text}} hier.%
   \footnote {\index{In Fussnote}Eine Fussnote}
   % ---
   \mainmatter
   \chapter {Kabidel}
   Viel Text\index{Text} hier; \emph{Auszeichnung\index{Auszeichnung}}
   \newpage
   Auf neuer\index{Seite}.
%  \textgreek{Καὶ ταῦτα μὲν δὴ ταῦτα}{}.
   Und so weiter.
   % ---
   \printindex
\end {document}
```

Answer (score 2):

First advice: wherever possible, if you need Greek, use `xetex` or `luatex` instead of `pdftex`. See the page on [Greek](https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-greek.html) in the babel site.

But if you want to stick to `pdftex`, just restore the default definition of `\@roman` as follows, before `\begin{document}`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@roman#1{\romannumeral #1}
\makeatother
```

The babel style for Greek redefines it even when Greek isn’t the main language, which doesn’t seem a good idea.

Second advice: `main=` should be used only when the default way to select the main language fails. The default way is:

```
\usepackage [greek.ancient, ngerman]{babel}
```

The main language is the last one.

**Update.**
With `xetex` or `luatex` and if all you need is a few phrases, you don’t even need to declare explicitly the Greek language (see the `babel` manual and the section on “Mostly monolingual documents”). The default LaTeX font doesn’t contain Greek letters, so you must declare it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont[ancientgreek]{rm}{NewComputerModern10}

\begin{document}

This is a piece of text from \foreignlanguage{ancientgreek}{Ὀδύσσεια},
taken from Wikisource: \foreignlanguage{ancientgreek}{Ἄνδρα μοι ἔννεπε,
Μοῦσα, πολύτροπον, ὃς μάλα πολλὰ πλάγχθη, ἐπεὶ Τροίης ἱερὸν πτολίεθρον
ἔπερσε}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I've already changed to XeTex.

Comment: Thx! So, the ultimate solution would be to let \@roman and \@Roman be changed only within the scope of the Greek language, wouldn't it? I've just created https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/170 and informed the babel-greek maintainer.

Comment: @wasadu I’ve update my answer with a minimal example with xetex/luatex.

Comment: @Javier It's all correct and good advice; but, might you possibly have missed the point a bit? I never had any difficulty getting the greek text into the document. The real problem was the wrongly generated index in the area of the `\frontmatter`.  Besides, with my installation, _NewComputerModern10_ is not known, and `\foreignlanguage{ancientgreek}{...}` produces a Babel warning: unknown language. @GeekestGeek: Thanks, perhaps I should have done that myself, but it didn't enter my head.

Comment: @wasadu Maybe a bit, but not quite. The point is, by using Greek in this way the `ldf` file for this language isn’t loaded at all and there are less chance of conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to overcome the problem is to use XeLaTeX and manually specify a font for greek (which of course does not mean it *is* the only way). Either package babel or polyglossia will do in this case. [In my real project this was quite a bit of work ... and it compiles *so utterly slow!*]

```
% compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass [paper=C5]{scrbook} 

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage {fontspec}
\usepackage [ngerman]{babel}  % english

\font\griik="[libertinusserif-regular.otf]" % any font with greek chars would do

\usepackage{imakeidx}      % mit xindy wird die Sache nicht besser
\makeindex[title=Riesenindex]

\begin {document}
   \frontmatter 
   Etwas Text\index{Text} hier;
   \newpage
   Etwas mehr Text\index{Text@\textsc{Text}} hier.%
   \footnote {\index{In Fussnote}Eine Fussnote}
   % ---
   \mainmatter
   \chapter {Kabidel}
   Viel Text\index{Text} hier; \emph{Auszeichnung\index{Auszeichnung}}
   \newpage
   Auf neuer\index{Seite}.
   {\griik Καὶ ταῦτα μὲν δὴ ταῦτα}
%  \textgreek{Καὶ ταῦτα μὲν δὴ ταῦτα}{}.
   Und so weiter.
   % ---
   \printindex
\end {document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mind, that the function `\textgreek` (similar to `\textcyrillic`) only changes the *font encoding*. It does not set the "Babel language" and does not
select Greek hyphenation patterns!

If you only need some symbols or words in the Greek script
(no hyphenation, no auto-strings, no enumerations, ...),
the simplest solution is to load the [textalpha](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/greek/greek-fontenc/textalpha.sty.html) package
(from [greek-fontenc](https://ctan.org/pkg/greek-fontenc))
instead of using Babel's "greek" option. Then either just use
Greek literal characters "anywhere" or replace
`\textgreek` -> `\ensuregreek`.

For correct hyphenation, translation of auto-generated strings,
Greek numerals instead of a transliteration of the Latin alphabet
in the second level of enumerations,
and fixes for issues with the non-standard LGR font encoding,
you should use the Greek option
and actually set the Greek \emph{language}, not just the emph{script}:
`\textgreek -> \foreignlanguage{greek}`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{textalpha}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Riesenindex]

\begin {document}
   \frontmatter 
   Etwas Text\index{Text} hier;
   \newpage
   Etwas mehr Text\index{Text@\textsc{Text}} hier.%
   \footnote {\index{In Fussnote}Eine Fussnote}
   % ---
   \mainmatter
   \chapter {Kabidel}
   Viel Text\index{Text} hier; \emph{Auszeichnung\index{Auszeichnung}}
   \newpage
   Auf neuer\index{Seite}.
   
   After loading \emph{textalpha}, you may use Greek literal characters
   anywhere in the document:
   This is fine for single upright symbols like π.
   
   For better kerning and to avoid needless font encoding switches, quotes
   should we wrapped in \verb|\ensuregreek|, if the document should be
   compiled with 8-bit TeX (pdftex).
   \ensuregreek{Καὶ ταῦτα μὲν δὴ ταῦτα.}

   % ---
   \printindex
\end {document}
```

The [babel-greek](https://codeberg.org/milde/greek-tex/src/branch/master/babel-greek) development version allows to work around the issue in the original document with the new, provisional modifier `local-LGR-fixes`.